what does the shape of this mapping look like?
Assume $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n,f(x)=Jf(x)\cdot x$ is a smooth mapping, and $Jf(0)=I$ with $Jf(x)$ is an orthogonal matrix at every point. Is $f$ the identity mapping? Here, $Jf(x)$ represents the Jacobian matrix of $f$, and $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Note: $Jf$ is the best linear approximation to $f$, and if $f$ is already a linear transformation, then $Jf \equiv f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Take any direction vector $v\in\mathbb S^1$ and consider the derivative of $f$ at some $x_0\in\mathbb R^n$ on direction $v$, we know
$$
{\partial f\over\partial v}(x_0)=Jf(x_0) \cdot v=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} {Jf(x_0+v \Delta t)(x_0+v \Delta t)-Jf(x_0) x_0\over\Delta t}\\
=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}{Jf(x_0+v\Delta t)-Jf(x_0)\over \Delta t}\cdot x_0+Jf(x_0)\cdot v
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}{Jf(x_0+v\Delta t)-Jf(x_0)\over \Delta t}\cdot x_0=0,\quad \forall x_0\in\mathbb R^n,v\in\mathbb S^1.
$$
Here we take $x_0=v$, and let $g(t):=Jf(t v)\cdot v$. The formula above gives $g'(t)\equiv 0$, therefore $g(t)\equiv{\rm Const}$, i.e. $f(tv)=t f(v)$ for any $v\in\mathbb S^1$ and $t\in\mathbb R$. Hence the derivative at $0$ on direction $v$ is
$$
v=Jf(0)\cdot v=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}{f(v\Delta t)\over \Delta t}=f(v),
$$
Therefore $f(x)\equiv x$, for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$.

Thank you for your answer. I think I understand now.
